# How to write proper boolean comparison for PostgreSQL in JOOQ

Tags: postgresql, jooq

I have a table t with boolean column b.

```
db.select(T.B).from(T).where(T.B.isTrue()).fetch();
db.select(T.B).from(T).where(T.B.eq(Boolean.TRUE)).fetch();
```

both these statements are translated to same sql query:

```
select "public"."T"."B" from "public"."T" where "public"."T"."B" = true;
```

and this is not working because for boolean comparison keywoard "is" must be used:

```
select "public"."T"."B" from "public"."T" where "public"."T"."B" is true;
```

Is there a way to write this properly?

Comment: Well yes, this works but if i want to write "is not true" it does not.
In my case column can contain null value.
I found a method .isDistinctFrom() which fits my case perfectly.

Comment: `postgres=# create table t (b boolean);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into t (b) values (null), (true), (false);
INSERT 0 3
postgres=# select * from t;
 b
---

 t
 f
(3 rows)

postgres=# select * from t where b != true;
 b
---
 f
(1 row)

postgres=# select * from t where b is not true;
 b
---

 f
(2 rows)`

Comment: well i cannot format it properly in comments but there is an example.
basically '=' operator does not include nulls

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question, don't post code or sample data in comments (or create an [online example](http://rextester.com/l/postgresql_online_compiler)) - your example in the comment is something different than the one in your question. If you had shown _that_ example in your question I would not have commented to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jOOQ currently doesn't support the SQL `<boolean test>` expression (i.e. `x IS [ NOT ] <truth value>`)

However, in the "true" case, this isn't really necessary anyway. You can pass the column to the where clause directly:

```
where(T.B)
```

... for the same effect. To get the inverse predicate, you can write

```
where(not(T.B))
```

If you want a null-safe comparison, you can also use [`Field.isNotDistinctFrom()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#isNotDistinctFrom-org.jooq.Field-) or [`Field.isDistinctFrom()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#isDistinctFrom-org.jooq.Field-)

```
where(T.B.isNotDistinctFrom(true))
where(T.B.isDistinctFrom(true))
```